# =Sum Formula VBA. Need loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula, sum

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ8FV.png)

I am trying to insert a new sum formula into column P that sums the corresponding values in column S. This process will repeat over as you will see in the image of my spreadsheet I have attached. Any ideas for creating a loop to do this?

Update: I figured out a loop that will do this here is my code.

```
Sub COMPLETE()

TotalRow = 0


SumEnd = 0


For cur_row = 3 To 174




If IsEmpty(Cells(cur_row, 19)) = True Then

If cur_row = 3 Then

TotalRow = 3

Counts = -1

Else

Cells(TotalRow, 25) = "=SUM(S" & (SumEnd - Counts) & ":S" & SumEnd & " )"


TotalRow = cur_row

Counts = -1

End If



Else:

Counts = Counts + 1


SumEnd = cur_row



 End If




Next cur_row
```

End Sub

Comment: There is no loop needed. You need to read [Relative and Absolute Cell References](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excelformulas/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/).

Comment: I should have clarified, I am looking to add this in as vba code to a macro I have written.

Comment: You should post your macro.

Comment: Do you want the macro to insert *formulas* into column P or just the values of the various sums?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot table to resume your data in that way:

[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUixH.png)

[Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKTm3.png)

Is that what you mean? or did you mean a VBA code?

Regards

Comment: So you can do a loop for each blank field in the column Q that puts the sum of the values of the column S and writes the result in the column P. What code do you have so far??

Answer (score 0):

For the example you gave, put this formula in cell P3 and fill down:

`=IF(LEN(S3)=0,SUM(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()+1&"C"&COLUMN(S3)&":R"&ROW()+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(S4:S$17="",0),0)-1&"C"&COLUMN(S3),FALSE)),"")`

Note that if your data extend past row 16, you need to change "S$17" to one cell *below* the last cell in column S.